# Is an algebraic isomorphism between two smooth complex projective varieties also a symplectic isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two smooth complex projective varieties. So in particular they are Kähler manifolds, and hence we can consider them as algebraic varieties as well as symplectic manifolds.

If $f:X \to Y$ is an isomorphism in the category of algebraic varieties, must it be an isomorphism in the category of symplectic manifolds (i.e., both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are symplectomorphisms)? I think the opposite is false.

Comment: Note that Kahler structure is non-unique, already for complex curves, so the answer is negative.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you elaborate a bit? Suppose we fix symplectic forms $\omega_X$ and $\omega_Y$ on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. If $f:X \to Y$ is an algebraic isomorphism, then we may not have $\omega_X = f^*\omega_Y$? I guess I am looking for a concrete counter-example.

Comment: Yes, even if $f=id$. As I said, just think about Riemann surfaces. How many Riemannian metrics in the given conformal class do you have?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Got you. Fixing the genus of a Riemann surface, then its algebraic structure determines a unique conformal structure, but we still have infinite choices of Riemannian structures (by scaling), and hence infinite choices of symplectic structures.